# Custom domains on heroku: Lost at setting Hostname/IP Address stage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns

I know custom domains on heroku comes up a lot but I'm lost.

The registrar wants this information specified:

```
Primary Nameserver
Nameserver:  
IP Address: 
Secondary Nameserver
Nameserver:  
IP Address: 
Extra Nameservers (Optional)
Nameserver: 
IP Address:
```

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains clearly states the IP Addresses to use so I entered those, but for the nameserver I was unsure. After some googling I thought proxy.heroku.com might work but it does not.

I emailed the registrar after I tried proxy.heroku.com and they said:

> You need to enter the IP addresses into the DNS zone file for
>
> HEROKU.COM associated with the name PROXY
>
> We cannot store IP addresses for .COM zones ....
>
> The reason why your name is not working is the Name Server
>
> PROXY.HEROKU.COM
>
> is not correctly configured.
>
> Please contact your DNS provider and ask them to fix it.

Now I'm very confused by the whole thing, perhaps it's the most obvious answer in the world but I just don't get it!

Help very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The registrar is asking you where you want to host your DNS (Not your website). Once you have your DNS setup, you can then point a specific subdomain to heroku.

You first need to setup some DNS hosting. (EasyDNS, Zerigo,... etc)